# Does Wonder woman celebrate...or even HAVE...a Birthday?

Tags: dc, wonder-woman

That's just about it. Considering she was literally *made* out of clay, she wasn't "technically" born, so... there's that. However, the amazons may celebrate the day she came to them. Since the current continuity Diana is seen as the daughter of Zeus,she must have been born in *some* way. Outside of that, Diana has shown a willingness to participate in and learn about common human customs, so a Birthday of her own would probably be one of them.

So yeah...does Diana have an official birth day?

Does she celebrate it, or has their been any instance seen of her celebrating it, in the old or new continuities?

And if so...when is it?

Comment: Happy Clay Day?

Answer (score 11):

According to the [1976 Super DC Calendar](http://www.5earths.info/about/dc-universe-calendar/) Diana Prince has her birthday on the 22nd of March.

[image]

Comment: Is that a canon source?

Comment: @Randal'Thor - As far as I'm aware, yes. Certainly quite a few of the birthdays mentioned here (for the first time) made their way into the comics

Comment: Impressive that they actually got the date of Purim right. It moves every year, and the Jewish calendar for that part of 1976 had a leap month, but that was indeed when it was celebrated.

Comment: Wait, so she's an Aries, like me? Cooooooooool!!!!!! That marks it for Pre Crisis; does this still count in Post-Crisis and New 52 continuities?

Comment: @Russhiro - Quite a few of them have been retconned over the years (largely, I suspect because the people writing the comics didn't know about this calendar) but not Diana Prince's as far as I can tell.

Comment: @ValorumNiiiiiiice! Superman is still in Feb, then?

Comment: @Russhiro - https://comicsalliance.com/happy-birthday-superman/